# Perforce Streams - Branching from imported stream

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate, perforce-stream

I have a stream (`parent_stream`) with some of the files set as "import" from the mainline stream.
I would like to create a child-stream in which all the files are branched and I am able to submit to them.

I know it is doable if I change the parent stream to be "shared" instead of "import", but I don't want to change the parent stream, I just need to branch from it.

Answer (score 0):

A stream can inherit imports from its parent stream that point back to some other stream, since it will never modify those files, but it may only branch from (and merge back to) its parent stream.

Since you want this stream to branch files from the mainline stream, it needs to be a child of the mainline stream, rather than a child of `parent_stream` which does not contain modifiable versions of those files.  (In a mainline model, *most* streams tend to be children of the mainline.)